# Find spectrum of $Af (x) = \int\limits_0^\pi \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty 5^{-n} \cos(nx)\cos(nt) f(t)\;dt$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory

I need to find spectrum of $Af (x) = \int\limits_0^\pi \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty 5^{-n} \cos(nx)\cos(nt) f(t)\;dt$ in $L_2[0,\pi]$.

I know that this operator is self-adjoint, so its residual spectrum is empty, and i tried to find its eigenvalues, but failed.

Solved:

$f(x) = \sum\limits_{m=1}^{\infty} a_m cos(mx)dx$

\begin{align*} Af(x) &= \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty 5^{-n} \cos(nx) \sum\limits_{m=1}^\infty a_m \int\limits_0^\pi cos(nt)cos(mt)dt \\\
 &= \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty 5^{-n} \cos(nx) \frac{\pi}{2} a_n 
\end{align*}

eigenvalues: $\{ \frac{5^{-n} \pi}{2}\}_{n=1}^\infty$

continius spectrum: $\{0\}$

Comment: Hint: Write $f(x)$ in terms of its cosine series $f(x) = \sum_n a_n\cos(nx)$. Then the cosine series of $Af(x)$ is readily determinable in terms of that of $f(x)$.

Comment: $f(x)=\sum_n \cos(n x)$ is not always valid for any continuous function because the injective map of Fourier series is not surjective.